Categorical data type in Tableau, such as in Python Pandas
When there is a limited count of categories in a Pandas column, we can optimize memory utilization in python by converting this column's dtype from object -> category.
How do I convert a column to categorical in Tableau?
I cannot find any similar date type in Tableau, is there anything related to?
Maybe there isn't even the need to optimize memory such as in python, is there?

You can make an extract for a Tableau data source, which is an efficient, columnar, heavily indexed cache of your data optimized for rapid read access. That is probably the closest analog to the Pandas categorical feature.
For large data sets, an extract can improve efficiency, especially if you hide unnecessary columns before making it and add filters (to reduce the size of the extract) Just realize that you are now reading from a cached local copy of (a subset of) your original data - so won’t see changes to your data — until you refresh or remove your extract.
There are more twists to extracts, but that’s the gist. They are available under the data menu.
